# Python string formatting on the fly

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have a situation where I don't necessarily know how I'd like to format some string until I've calculated the length of some other number.

Doing something like:

```
"{0:.2f}".format(#)
```

works well because I know that I'd like to display that many places, two in this case, past the decimal point. What if the number of places is subject to change? How would I do dynamic string formatting of the elements of a list called B (that is I'd like to place appropriately formatted elements of B into a string), from the corresponding elements of a list called A?

```
A = ['1.100','5.4','11.1','7']
B = [1.23474927,4.92837087,12.06532387,6.9998123]
```

The answer that I would ideally like to see is the following:

```
C = ['1.235','4.9','12.1','7']
```

Here's what I know so far:

1) I can figure out how many places to the right of each string within A by doing:

```
places_A = [len(A[i].partition('.')[2]) for i in range(len(A)]
```

The real question is: How do I then dynamically tell format() to keep that many places to the right of the decimal point?

Comment: Theres nothing wrong with using a variable as the format. eg, `fmt="{0:.2f}"` and then `fmt.format(#)`

Comment: this is valid, for instance `("{0:." + str(places_A) + "f}").format(A)`

Comment: @Octopus he wants to know how to make the .2 variable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need more cowbells (actually, more replacements: `{}`):

```
print "This is a number with {1} places {0:.{1}f}".format(3.14159, 2)
```

Or, in the example you gave:

```
C = ['{0:.{1}f}'.format(b, len(a.partition('.')[2])) for a,b in zip(A,B)]
```

Comment: Excellent - this is exactly what I was looking for! Nice reference, too.

Comment: Well, `{` does sort of look like a cowbell on its side. I officially propose a new name: `{}` brackets are hereafter to be referred to as "cowbells."

Answer (score 3):

With classical string formatting:

```
>>> d = 2
>>> f = "%%.%sf" % d
>>> f
'%.2f'
>>> f % 5.0
'5.00'
```

That is, first dynamically create your format string, and then use that format string for converting your float to a string. That concept is translatable to the modern string formatting syntax.